# Reuse of vertical group of buttons in few pages using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my application, there is vertical group of buttons which is common in few pages. It should be at the same space in those pages, rendering different forms between left navigation to this right side group of buttons. We can say their is this right or center navigation in layout for few pages.

How should I achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use php and include them

Comment: That will work if they are using `php` what about `vb.net`? lol

Comment: are you just using html or do you have some server side language

Comment: He doesn't know what he wants.

Comment: actually this button group should look like part of layout for those few pages,I'm using bootstrap and gsp

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jquery**

Put your buttons in its own `.html` file like `buttons.html` with `.load()` in main html file.

```
$('#WhereYouWantItID').load('whatfolder/buttons.html');
```

This will load the `buttons.html` file to a specific target on your page

**Could someone edit my answer so it makes more sense? I read this and it makes it sound harder then it really is**

Comment: thank you! I am using responsive framework ,right now I have developed in loading pattern only but I want the button group to be part of lay out for those few pages and form should be rendered in that fixed space .

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve that using `iframe` in HTML. If you are using server side language like `PHP`, i would not recommend you to use this.

menu.html

```
<a href="test.html">Test Page</a> |
<a href="test.html">Another Page</a>
```

home.html

```
<iframe src="menu.html"></iframe>
```

index.html:

```
<iframe src="menu.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: thank you! I am using gsp and bootstrap and its responsive framework so I'm avoiding to use iframe